# Properties page not displaying in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Team Development Edition and my Project properties page will not display.  I right-clicked the project name and selected "Properties" and no page displayed as it normally would.  Also, when I double-click the Settings.settings the normal Settings GUI does not display.   I only see the XML in the Settings.settings file.  Please Help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the uninstallation of an add-on is what caused my problem.  Reinstalling Visual Studio did not seem to help, so I took extreme measures and reformatted my machine.

Comment: In my case, re-installing the add-on fixed the issue. It was AnkhSVN that I had uninstalled when the issue started to happen for me.

Comment: Yep, AnkhSVN for me too was the problem on vs 2008 properties not showing up.  Thanks!!!

Comment: If you think reformatting was an appropriate solution you are wasting the time of more knowledgeable people and your own asking questions like these.

Answer (score 2):

Open the command line and change the directory to your visual studio install directory.

Run devenv /setup

What this basically does is reset your visual studio to the original installation state and resetting the installed packages.

Found the solution here : [Property Window is Blank in Visual Studio 2008](http://codingsmarter.com/post/2008/05/14/Property-Window-is-Blank-in-Visual-Studio-2008.aspx)

The MSDN Entry is here: [/setup (devenv.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6a2fad%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: devenv /setup fixed the same problem in my machine.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After re-install my system, i ran into this as well. Here is how I resulted this problem.

1. in the Solution Explorer, right-click the solution item, and select "Unload Project"
2. right-click again, and select "Reload Project".

Answer (score 2):

```
devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The properties page can be displayed when not doing anything else.

Try going to View -> Properties Window and see if its displayed.  Or try the keyboard shortcut CTRL-W, P

Comment: I'm not trying to see that properties window.  I'm trying to see the project properties window.  The place that has all the build settings and where you sign the assembly etc...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using multiple monitors? Or were you at some point, and no longer?

I have noticed the Project Properties window opening on the wrong monitor sometimes. So maybe it does open it but in the old position.

To test this, open VS, open your solution, right-click on your project and select Properties. Now press [Alt+Space], [M], [Right-arrow] and now move your mouse around. The window should move to your current monitor.

There is also a Window->Reset Window Layout menu, which you could try, but it doesn't seem to affect the Project Properties window.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post: ["Unspecified error" in Visual Studio 2008 when trying to view project properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527224/unspecified-error-in-visual-studio-2008-when-trying-to-view-project-properties)

You may need to install the x64 components for Visual Studio 2008. They can be found the install disk. Add Features -> C++

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit late in responding.  My "properties page Shift+F4" was greyed out, but F4 by itself seemed to open the properties dialog I wanted. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

F4 brings up the missing property window.  I found that hidden in the Microsoft documentation.  At least it worked on my vb 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you opened the solution or it may be pointing to your local folder from file explorer.