# "unspecified error" visual studio 2008 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I set my active solution from Win32 to x64, I cannot build the project or view the properties.

When I try to build my project, it is skipped.

When I try to view the properties, the first time I try, nothing happens. The second time, I get an error message saying, "The operation could not be completed. Unspecified error".

I am running Visual Studio 2008 sp1.

The project compiles correctly on another computer.
[Tried solution provided @](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527224/unspecified-error-in-visual-studio-2008-when-trying-to-view-project-properties)

but couldn't locate the "x64 components for Visual Studio 2008".

Answer (score 3):

If the Visual Studio edition you are using allows creating 64-bit code, you should check if the 64-bit compiler is installed.

[image: Check this image]

Answer (score 1):

VS 2008 Pro doesn't install the 64-bit compiler and tools by default. You have to explicitly select them during the installation.

Control Panel -> Uninstall Programs.
Select Visual Studio and click Uninstall/Change.
Wait. Wait some more. Click Next.
Choose Add or Remove Features.
Expand MSVC 2008 -> Language Tools -> Visual C++.
Select X64 Compilers and Tools.
You'll probably need your original installation media.

Once the 64-bit compiler and tools are installed, you should be able to add a 64-bit configuration to your solution.(via [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979675/visual-studio-2008-c-no-x64-platform))

Comment: Thanks @miss Panda... Totally unaware of this . it works .