# C/C++ file properties not showing in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Got this strange Visual Studio's behavior: when I open properties pages for C/C++ files, the C/C++ properties do not show.

The short description seems similar to ['Properties page not displaying in Visual Studio 2008'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231034/), but it is actually quite different – the pages display as they should, also a tree of properties' categories are shown, and even the General properties display when clicked (Excluded From Build: No; Item Type: C/C++ compiler), but the whole C/C++ category tree shows no properties, and even no properties grid:

[image: mising C/C++ properties for a file]
[link to a full-resolution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Adh.png)

When I click the project, C/C++ properties are shown as usual, together with Linker properties and all other groups:

[image: C/C++ properties for a project]
[link to a full-resolution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvPlE.png)

I tried to refresh the installation with setup.exe from the original installation disk, but that didn't help. Then I uninstalled the IDE and re-installed it back. Tried `devenv /setup` reconfiguration command, too.

Now I have no idea what I should check/fix next.

Forgot to specify OS: VS2010 + SP1, Win 7 Ultimate + SP1, 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Is something else also selected along with C++ file in Visual Studio ?
Typically Visual Studio will show a Property page empty if objects from multiple selection does not have common properties. e.g. if you select a c++ file and solution at the top, a blank property page would appear.

Comment: Nope, I select a single item (a .cpp source file) and some properties are displayed correctly and are available for modification (the 'General' subset), while other do not display at all (the whole 'C/C++' subset). The same subset for a project item displays correctly, and modifications made there cause appropriate effects during build (e.g. assembly listing is or is not generated, preprocesor symbols are defined, etc.) However, I need to set some properties for specific modules only, and setting them on the project level is nof satisfactory.

Comment: I had found a link to similar issue and solution below,
https://shiftkeysoftware.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/the-case-of-the-visual-studio-blank-properties-window/?preview=true&preview_id=10&preview_nonce=27a29efe52

Please check whether your problem has similar characteristics and the solution mentioned there works in your case.

Comment: Thank you, I've seen that page, that's where I got the idea of using `devenv /setup`. Anyway I'll give it a second try soon. In the meantime I found similar problem at social.msdn.microsoft [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/db1c99f7-dd3e-4e0e-944b-172b2148ec23/visual-studio-2005-properties-window-blank-in-aspnet-source-view?forum=vssetup) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/f3808fad-c172-410d-9aa4-de0ae57b6054/properties-window-cleareddisableddisappears?forum=vssetup) but they don't apply – those were caused by SP1 for VS2005.

Comment: Is your issue resolved now ? What was final solution ?